# How can I represent the first order logic "All men are tall unless they are short."?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

How can I represent the following phrase in first order logic `"All man are tall unless they are short."` ?

Consider that I have the unary predicates `Man(x)`, `Tall(x)`, `Short(x)`

I was thinking something like below, but it doesn't capture the fact that x is a man:

```
all x (- Short(x) -> Tall(x))
```

Comment: For every $x$, if $x$ is a man, then $x$ is either tall or short.

Comment: @AlvinL , something like `all x (Man(x) -> (Short(x) | Tall(x))).` ?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4249347/21813).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final answer:

For all $x, \Big($Man$(x) \to \big(\,$Short$(x)$ or Tall$(x)\,\big)\Big).$